# MS Access 2016 report contains a hyperlink pathway. On Click event VBA to open specific hyperlink clicked

Tags: vba, ms-access, hyperlink, report

I have a report based on a search parameter form.
Is it possible to use a textbox named txtFullScanPathway included on the report as a hyperlink to open that specific pdf in an On Click Event perhaps?.

Alternatively, is there a way to have another form in datasheet based on the parameter form to open the results?

The project purpose is to allow a quick search of PDF Manifests... the user will open a report using a command button on the parameter form (This is all working now) and there may be several to go through.

The Report generated has a file pathway which has been generated by the parameter form, and that field is "FullScanPathway".

The user is trying to find a pdf based on this "manifest" and so there may be several results to look through and I was hoping to provide an "On Click" event to open the pdf that belongs to FullScanPathway...

Are there any good examples on how to accomplish this?

I have tried the Follow Hyperlink method, but do not like the security errors it throws...

Any help or ideas would be sincerely appreciated !

William

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim wsShell As Object
Set wsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsShell.Run Chr(34) & Me!FullScanPathway & Chr(34)
Set wsShell = Nothing
```